# How to get inner text using relative path?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the inner text of a element when click on another element.

How can I get the value "ABC DEF" when click on id **xxyyzz**?

Can you help me to resolve this with javascript. Not JQuery

I tried following code.

```js
function myfunction(id) {
    let clickElement = document.getElementById(id)
    let name = clickElement.parentNode.nextSibling;
    alert(name);
}
```

```html
<div class="row mb-1">
    <div class="col-md-6 pt-2">ABC DEF</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-bars p-3" id="xxyyzz" onclick="myfunction(this.id)"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

but it returns **undefined**

Comment: You'll note that the element you are after is the [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling) not the the `nextSibling`. Also you don't need to re-query the element, you can access the `event.currentTarget` to get a reference to the element that the listener is attached to.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `nextSibling` to `previousElementSibling`

Because, the `parentNode` from your code will target the immediate div `col-md-6` which has the previous element that you are looking for `<div class="col-md-6 pt-2">ABC DEF</div>`

```
function myfunction(id) {
    let clickElement = document.getElementById(id)
    let name = clickElement.parentNode.previousElementSibling.innerText;
    alert(name);
}
```

**Optimized Version**

HTML

```
<div class="row mb-1">
    <div class="col-md-6 pt-2">ABC DEF</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-bars p-3" id="xxyyzz" onclick="myfunction(event)"> test </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function myfunction(event) {
  console.log(event)
    let name = event.currentTarget.parentNode.previousElementSibling.innerText;
    alert(name);
}
```